# Return type of array concat

Tags: typescript

I have a method that makes an array of flattend objects from a nested object.

```
{a: 'b',
 c: {d: 'e'}
}
```

will be

```
[{a: 'b'}, {d:'e'}]
```

So the return type of this method is an array of objects (`Record<string, any>[]`). But Typescript gives the following error:

**TS2769: No overload matches this call.
...
Argument of type 'Record<string, any>[] | { [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray'. Type 'Record<string, any>[]' is not assignable to type 'ConcatArray'.**

What would be the correct return type of the `_flatten` method:

```
const _flatten = (obj: Record<string, any>): Record<string, any>[] =>  
    [].concat(...Object.keys(obj)
             .map((key: string) => (
                   typeof obj[key] === 'object' ? _flatten(obj[key]) : { [key]: obj[key] }
             ))
         );
```

Comment: The main problem is that you're mapping - that means that the result is either a single object or an array of objects. You can just use `flatMap` to solve that and you also get rid of the need to do `[].concat(... /*mapping*/)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the error message is this:

```
Type 'Record<string, any>[]' is not assignable to type 'ConcatArray<never>'
```

That's because you used `[].concat` and `[]` is type of `never[]`.

Try to use `Array.prototype.concat` instead:

```
const _flatten = (obj: Record<string, any>): Record<string, any>[] =>  
    Array.prototype.concat(...Object.keys(obj)
             .map((key: string) => (
                   typeof obj[key] === 'object' ? _flatten(obj[key]) : { [key]: obj[key] }
             ))
         );
```

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gMwDYEMpQKZhgXhgChACMArALhgCUNQAnAEwB5paBLMAcwBoYUwBPAHwBKCtTpMW7brwGCA2gF1cgmDACwAKDVqAgrVop+AOgAOtEFEv9TGY6DDA0+Y64DypGlGMBrDPwhCUmEtHTDwmGMAWxRTfHw-fgopTmEVAlCIrPCoGwwQBBhiEnlE5RwKmAByYq8qmAB+eGQ0TDAgkrK0igBvGFL-RQpigf5lAF9M7J1hEO1s4QBuIA)

Or you can typehint `[]` like this one:

```
([] as any[]).concat(/* omitted */)
```

Comment: thank you, you saved me so much time :)